# How do I list subpages in post editor view?

Tags: wp-admin, child-pages

I have many pages, each with many subpages nested up to 5 levels deep. In order to find a specific page in the administration panel, I can search for it on the list of all pages. The search results page does not show the subpages (rightly so). Is there perhaps a way to list the subpages of a page in the page's editor view?

Comment: it shows really just parent or until a certain level of subpage?

Comment: @AndréKelling, it shows the subpages if they also match the search criteria.